# Fixed decimal numbers with JAVA

Tags: java, numbers

How  do I  represent numbers in the  format

```
001 = 1
002 = 2
003 = 3
010 = 10
020 = 20
```

The number  of  digits  is   always  3.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It's difficult to infer what you need by reading your post. Keep in mind that in Java, if you trail a number literal with `0` it means it's an octal number.

Comment: Do you mean what data structure to use, or how to format the number properly for display?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to output integers such that they always have leading zeros, use String.format with a zero before the number of digits in the format string, for example:

```
int i = 3;
String s = String.format("%03d", i);
System.out.println(s);
```

Gives the output:

```
003
```

Comment: Indeed, although it is likely the poster wants to do something other than simply send the string to stdout. Maybe I should split the example to show explicitly how to construct the string... (I'll do that now)

Comment: Why is my eclipse saying I need to make i an Object[]? It won't let me make it an int.

Comment: @Gareth: I guess you disabled autoboxing. Literally it reads `String.format("%03d", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(i)});`. There are two objects created, one for varargs and one for autoboxing.

Comment: @maaartinus yep that was it. Figured it out after some coffee. Miracle drug that stuff. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.valueOf("020")` is sufficient for your purpose. It will give you 20 as a result. After that you can use it as `Integer`, `int` or `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(3);
System.err.println(decimalFormat.format(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
String  num_str = "001"
Integer val     = Integer.parseInt(num_str);
String  answer  = val.toString();
```