# String.format won't allow int

Tags: java, eclipse, string-formatting

I was looking for a quick easy way to format a int into a string with two leading zeros. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377337/47690 answer and it looked like what I needed. So I implemented it as such

```
int i = 34; //could be any value but you get the idea   
String.format("%03d", i);
```

But, Eclipse seems to moan about the fact that String.format requires an `Object[]` for its second parameter. What is going on here?

Comment: The code's fine. What versions of Java and Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Can you please (always) also post the complete error message?

Comment: Runs for me too.. Try cleaning your project in Eclipse:  `Project -> Clean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you project settings

```
project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level
```

you are probably in Java 1.4 which does not recognize vararg

```
String format(String format, Object ... args)
```

Comment: I could kick myself for not look for this first.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print the value of `i`, you can use:

```
System.out.printf("%03d", i);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", i));
```

**EDIT :**

<strike>Also I tried your code in Java 6 and it did not work. So, I used printf().</strike>
Ohh. sorry! I cleaned the project and it worked.

I am using Java 6 and Eclipse Helios.

Comment: Useful tip, but doesnt answer the question :). Strangely I tried in Java 6 and it still compiled in Eclipse.. hmm

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles and runs fine under Java 7 (and Eclipse Juno SR1 is happy with it):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 42;   
        System.out.println(String.format("%03d", i));
    }
}
```

The error message is a red herring: even though the final argument is `Object...` (aka `Object[]`), auto-boxing takes care of everything.

I suspect you're using an outdated version of Java and/or Eclipse, or the compiler compliance level in your Eclipse project is set to pre-1.5 (even if you are using 1.5+).

Comment: It could be the language level of the project. If it is set to an older version, auto unboxing might be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

String s = String.format("%04d", i);

This code stands for 4 digits in a number to string so.. if u use %04d i will get two trialing zeros up front

Though int i is a primitive and its expecting object as its argument,

its JVM will takes care internally to converts into object data type

see this as per java  implementation ..

```
public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
}
```

Sample code for appending zeros dynamically...

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class ArrayTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 34; //could be any value but you get the idea   
    int zeroCount = 2;

    String s = String.format("%d", i);
    int length = s.length()+zeroCount;

    System.out.println(String.format("%0"+length+"d", i));

    // second way u can achieve 
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    decimalFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(length);
    System.err.println(decimalFormat.format(i));
}
```

}

And coming to the arguments of System.format it can take infinite no. of parameters as its a varargs object as second parameter

Check this url
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29