# Java: Lead 0 in double and 1 digit after a dot

Tags: java, string, double

I want to format a double to string with the max length is 7 which contains a dot "." and one digit after it.
For example:

```
 123.4 becomes "00123.4"
 12345 becomes "12345.0"
 12345.63 becomes "12345.6"
```

Any help, please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed decimal numbers with JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377209/fixed-decimal-numbers-with-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
double test = 33333.327;

String formatted = String.format("%07.1f", test)

System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: Edit your answer, then I'm able to revoke my vote. Sry.

Comment: You have a +1 now. Thanks for revealing that misunderstanding of mine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000.0");
```

...

```
System.out.println(df.format(123.4)); -> 00123.4
System.out.println(df.format(12345)); -> 12345.0
System.out.println(df.format(12345.63)); -> 12345.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%07.1f", myDouble);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html